# How to implement fluent api in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, fluent-interface

I want to implement fluent api to my mvc sites. I got the basics.
So implement object library such as:

```
public class UIElement{/*...*/}
public class ButtonBase : UIElement{/*...*/}
public class LinkButton : ButtonBase {/*...*/}

  public static class Extensions
  {
    public static T UIElementMethod<T>(this T element, string title)
      where T : UIElement
    {
      return element;
    }

    public static T ButtonBaseMethod<T>(this T element, string title)
      where T : ButtonBase
    {
      return element;
    }

    public static T LinkButtonMethod<T>(this T element, string title)
      where T : LinkButton
    {
      return element;
    }
  }
```

But how to use it in razor view without some flush method calling.

```
@Html.UIproject().LinkButton()
    .UIElementMethod("asd")
    .ButtonBaseMethod("asd")
    .LinkButtonMethod("asd")
```

But it returns the name of the class. I tried to make an implicit operator to MvcHtmlString but it's not called.
Any idea how to achieve this. How to know it's the and of the chain. I like the way how the  [Kendo UI](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/) work.

Thanks,
Péter

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `UIElement` classes need to implement the `IHtmlString` interface. This interface's `ToHtmlString` method gets called by Razor and should return an HTML-encoded string.

So I would implement this on the abscract base `UIElement` and create `RenderHtml` method which can be implemented by the concrete `LinkButton`, etc. classes:

```cs
public abstract class UIElement : IHtmlString 
{
    public string ToHtmlString()
    {
        return RenderHtml(); // This should return an HTML-encoded string.
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ToHtmlString();
    }

    protected abstract string RenderHtml();
}
```

If you check KendoUI in Reflector/JustDecompile/dotPeek in the `WidgetBase` class you will see the same pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, in this particular situation, but you might be able to use an implicit cast to convert from a fluent builder to the object you need (see this [blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2010/12/09/fluent-builders-part-2.aspx)).